# How to use readLine from JSSC

Tags: serial, programming

When I use JSSC and call `serialPort.readLine(event.getEventValue())` from `public void serialEvent(SerialPortEvent event)` I've got fragments, not all string. What I must do to get all string from begin to `"\r\n"`? What I must do to get all string from my start marker (like `"[start]"`) to my stop marker (like `"[stop]"`)? What to modify in this code:

```
private static class PortReader implements SerialPortEventListener {
    public void serialEvent(SerialPortEvent event) {
        if(event.isRXCHAR() && event.getEventValue() > 0){
            try {
                String data = serialPort.readString(event.getEventValue());
                serialPort.writeByte((byte) 1);
            }
            catch (SerialPortException ex) {
                System.out.println(ex);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the relationship to Arduino. Your question is about Java!

Comment: Anyone who uses jSSC (the most common Java serial library) to interface with the Arduino will have to implement this, so I'll answer it.

Comment: Indeed, this is a problem that will be faced by those trying to use Arduino (or similar) with a larger system.  It should either be open as an appropriate question here, or sent to stackoverflow.  Probably it is more useful here - there it may simply get lost (though if it had not been answered here, sending it there in search of more eyeballs could have made sense)

Comment: @ChrisStratton since this is more of a Java question, this doesn't belong here. I'll see if SO will take it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The event gets fired when a single character is received, not the whole string. You have to build the string up until you get to `\r\n` and then process it. This is my code for a similar project. It uses a protocol where `>` signifies the start of a message and `\r` signifies the end. `processMessage` is a function to process the entire message and update GUI elements etc. It is invoked using `runLater` because the serialEvent function will be on a different thread to the GUI thread.

```
StringBuilder message = new StringBuilder();
Boolean receivingMessage = false;
public void serialEvent(SerialPortEvent event) {
    if(event.isRXCHAR() && event.getEventValue() > 0){
        try {
            byte buffer[] = serialPort.readBytes();
            for (byte b: buffer) {
                if (b == '>') {
                    receivingMessage = true;
                    message.setLength(0);
                }
                else if (receivingMessage == true) {
                    if (b == '\r') {
                        receivingMessage = false;
                        String toProcess = message.toString();
                        Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
                            @Override public void run() {
                                processMessage(toProcess);
                           }
                        });
                    }
                    else {
                        message.append((char)b);
                    }
                }
            }                
        }
        catch (SerialPortException ex) {
            System.out.println(ex);
            System.out.println("serialEvent");
        }
    }
}
```

A simpler version for you might be the following. `processMessage` is called whenever a `\r` or `\n` is received and there are some bytes in the message.

```
StringBuilder message = new StringBuilder();
public void serialEvent(SerialPortEvent event) {
    if(event.isRXCHAR() && event.getEventValue() > 0){
        try {
            byte buffer[] = serialPort.readBytes();
            for (byte b: buffer) {
                    if ( (b == '\r' || b == '\n') && message.length() > 0) {
                        String toProcess = message.toString();
                        Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
                            @Override public void run() {
                                processMessage(toProcess);
                           }
                        });
                        message.setLength(0);
                    }
                    else {
                        message.append((char)b);
                    }
            }                
        }
        catch (SerialPortException ex) {
            System.out.println(ex);
            System.out.println("serialEvent");
        }
    }
}
```

**Edit:**

Two things fixed:  1. Using `StringBuilder` instead of `String` to save making a lot objects every time the message is incremented. 2. Make a copy of the message string before passing to `runLater` otherwise when it does run it will use the up to date version of the string, which could have new characters, and thus cause problems.

**Edt 2:**
On Windows I found it needed `if(event.isRXCHAR() && event.getEventValue() > 0)` as the event would sometimes be fired with 0 bytes causing a null point exception in `for (byte b: buffer)`

Comment: Thak you very much. Maybe it will be better to add your answer to FAQ or something else.

Comment: @oventarb I hope you get this message - please see the updated code, there was a big error in the initial one. I had been using the erroneous code for a while myself and only just fixed it.